# Notation in probability and staticstics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

I am not familiar with the notation $$Z \equiv X \land Y.$$ for two random variables $X$ and $Y$. (In the problem they are independent exponential random variables.)

Does it mean joint distribution?

Comment: Maybe it means the minimum between the two.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

So far it is a notation for minimum, at least in my course. Similarly $\vee$ represents maximum.